Trying to identify a cartoon from the 70's or 80's
There were 3 airplanes, and they combined into one to make a robot. But the robot changed depending on the order that they combined. So there were 3 larger robots depending on the combination. 
Each episode was about one of the larger robots fighting an enemy, so in the opening credits you saw the combination and knew "Oh, this is an episode about....". 
Probably Japanese, and around late 70's or early 80's.

Sounds like Getter Robo!  This was a TV series that originally aired on Fuji TV between April 4, 1974 to May 8, 1975.  This fits your timeline.
As for the three planes combining into 3 different robots depending on their combination:
"The plot involves three strong-willed teenagers: Ryoma Nagare, Hayato Jin and Musashi Tomoe, who pilot three specially designed combat jets (Eagle, Jaguar, and Bear) which can be combined together into three different giant robots, Getter-1 (balanced and for flight combat), Getter-2 (fast and for ground combat), and Getter-3 (strong and for marine combat)."
This series was the progenitor of the combined transformation mecha genre.

Thanks for your response but the show I am thinking of is not Getter Robo.
